# How to find storage space of an Image Template is taking?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was told that SoftLayer charges $0.25 per GB for storage space used by each of the image template created.  I've created a virtual guest and create an image template using it.  How do I know how much space it has taken for storing the generated image template?

How can I get this information using SoftLayer service APIs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will return all your images templates and the disk space for them:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectMask=mask[children[blockDevices[diskImage]]]
```

you can see the value for the "diskSpace" field under "blockDevices" e.g.

```
blockDevices": 
  {
"device": "0"
"diskImageId": 12456903
"diskSpace": 36381956096
"groupId": 883223
"id": 1065801
"units": "B"
```

in case your image template have more than 1 disk you have to sum all the diskspaces.

Regards

Comment: Thank you! That did give what I was looking for!